# Counter increment in state not updating

Tags: reactjs

The larger problem is when I set the state it does not work. I've tried to break the problem down here, but sadly this doesn't match my error exactly. Still, the behaviour, and the way it fails, is the same as mine.

I have a counter in state that should be updated on click, and this should trigger my pagination. But the first click does not update properly. Since the counter does not increment as is should, it throws off the `pagination` func below. The fiddle at the bottomw shows it all together.

This is what I want: https://jsfiddle.net/drumgod/n5u2wwjg/262413/ A counter that increments as it should.

That fiddle works so my problem must be somewhere else in the code. Basic idea is this:

1.click button to increment counter by 30

2.counter slices array that does pagination

3.items appear on page

Problem is:

1. Call `pagination` and counter does not increment.
2. Logic inside `pagination` is off.
3. Items do not appear on page.

Example code:

```
    //should add 30 to state each time but does not on first click

     countBy30() {
           this.setState((prevState => ({
           counter: prevState.counter + 30
       })))
       return this.state.counter
       }

       //func to do pagination by slicing arr

       paginate(arr) {
    // calling here should add 30 but does not on click
           let count = this.countBy30()
     //slices up array - counter seems to screw up this slicing?
          let sliceStart = count - 30
          let sliceEnd = count
          let chunk = arr.slice(sliceStart, sliceEnd)
          return  chunk
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/drumgod/705t1oc8/55/

In the fiddle when the button `Next 30` is clicked the number does increment in the render, but it does not change the list until the second click. This is because the slicing in the `pagination` func is off by 30 for some reason.

(Since the fiddle is very busy, go straight to `countBy30` in fiddle as I think above that is working.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `paginate` is assuming that `countBy30` returns the new state value, but state is updated asynchronously, so `countBy30` is returning the old value and then paginate is using that to make other changes to state.

You should rework the code so that you determine your new state in its entirety and then set that in a single 'setState' call (i.e. `updatePageState` should set `chunkComments` and `counter`).

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/705t1oc8/64/) showing this.

The main changes were:

Added the following to your constructor:

```
this.updatePageState = this.updatePageState.bind(this);
```

Changed your `then` from:

```
.then(items => {
                    // filter out undefined
                    let comments = items.filter(obj => obj)
                    console.log('c', comments)
                    // push all comments to state
                    this.setState({
                        fullComments: [...comments]
                    })
                    // paginate comments on load
                    let obj = this.paginate(this.state.fullComments)
                    console.log('original obj', obj)
                    // set first 30 to state
                    this.setState({
                        chunkComments: obj
                    })
                })
```

to:

```
.then(items => {
                    // filter out undefined
                    let comments = items.filter(obj => obj)
                    console.log('c', comments)
                    // push all comments to state
                    let counterAndChunk = this.paginate(comments);
                    this.setState({
                        fullComments: [...comments],
                        ...counterAndChunk
                    });
                })
```

and changed `paginage` and `updatePageState` from:

```
    paginate(arr) {
    //increment and get current count
        let count = this.countBy30()
        console.log('count', count)
        let sliceStart = count - 30
/* console.log('start', sliceStart)
 */        let sliceEnd = count
/* console.log('end', sliceEnd) */
        let chunk = arr.slice(sliceStart, sliceEnd)
        /* console.log('chunk', chunk) */
        return chunk
    }
    updatePageState(arr) {
        let obj = this.paginate(arr)
        //console.log('paginate obj', obj)
        this.setState({
            chunkComments: obj
        })
        //console.log('new state', this.state)
    }
```

to:

```
    paginate(arr) {
    //increment and get current count
        let count = this.state.counter + 30;
        console.log('count', count)
        let sliceStart = count - 30
/* console.log('start', sliceStart)
 */        let sliceEnd = count
/* console.log('end', sliceEnd) */
        let chunk = arr.slice(sliceStart, sliceEnd)
        /* console.log('chunk', chunk) */
        return {chunkComments: chunk, counter: count};
    }
    updatePageState() {
        let newState = this.paginate(this.state.fullComments)
        //console.log('paginate obj', obj)
        this.setState(newState)
        //console.log('new state', this.state)
    }
```

and changed:

```
<button onClick = {() => {this.updatePageState(this.state.fullComments)}} >
```

to:

```
<button onClick = {this.updatePageState}>
```

Comment: What is happening here? `this.setState({
                        fullComments: [...comments],
                        ...counterAndChunk
                    });`

Comment: This answer def solved the issue here, but not my overall issue. I pass the `chunkComments` down through 2 child components. The lowest down of the two is a template but it is not receiving the data I pass in as props, except on mount. Even though the data is clearly correct when I log it out in the parent. I guess I need a way to replicate this, and then ask another question. Thanks!!

Comment: `this.setState({ fullComments: [...comments], ...counterAndChunk });` is using [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) and is equivalent to `this.setState({ fullComments: [...comments], counter: counterAndChunk.counter,  chunkComments: counterAndChunk.chunkComments });`

Comment: Got it. Your more verbose explanation helps me see the functionality and what is being shortened

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways i could implement this kind of functionality.

You could decide to use just one react component to handle the counter and the pagination. like I show below.

```
export default class PaginationWithCounter extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //initialize counter and data
        this.state = {
            counter: 30,
            data: []
        };

        this.incrementCounter = this.incrementCounter.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //make ajax call and load data
    }

    //reacts to click events
    incrementCounter() {
        this.setState(prevState => {counter: prevState.counter + 30});
    }

    render() {
        const {data, counter} = this.state;
        const page = data.slice(counter - 30, counter); //load up to 30 items
        //render the page and the button
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {/**iterate through the page array and display them*/}
                </ul>
                <button onClick={this.incrementCounter}>increment{counter}</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

You can also decide to have a pagination component and a counter component. In this case, the counter component accepts a paginate callback prop from the pagination component, which it calls whenever there is a click.