# Stateless functional component updates while stateful version does not

Tags: reactjs, debugging

I get data from and API async and, I thought, solved the related timing issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54046773/counter-increment-in-state-not-updating/54047023?noredirect=1#comment94969955_54047023), but I still have issues with the render not updating.

Since my component would not update I broke it down to a basic stateless version and then it started working. I've tried to make identical versions of the components, +/- state. Only the stateless version works as I said, but I need the full component to work so I can do stuff with the state. Otherwise I'd use it as is, stateless.

(Side note: Not sure if this is 'React-ful', but I use only props in the example in the full React.Component, never setting anything to state. Moving on...)

Full version component - [unworking fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drumgod/pbsv02jL/68/)

```
class Posts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {};
    this.posts = props.data;
  }
  render() {
    return this.posts.map((post, index) => {
     return (
        <div className="comment" key={index}>
          <div className="by">{post.by}</div>
          <div className="id">{post.id}</div>
        </div>
      )
    })
  }
 }
```

stateless functional - [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drumgod/d2mbaqv4/36/)

```
function Posts(props) {
  let posts = props.data;
  return posts.map((post, index) => {
    return (
      <div className="comment" key={index}>
        <div className="by">{post.by}</div>
        <div className="id"> {post.id}</div>
      </div>
    )
 })
}
```

For some reason the full component does not re-render on click while the stateless does. I thought I resolved the timing issues but perhaps not? Is the component type truly causing the thing to break/work? Why?

I tried to make the only difference btw the fiddles the way `Posts` is structured, still the fiddles are quite busy. Hopefully though more effective in showing my problem than showing the code here.

Comment: Why are you rebinding the props? Just use `this.props.posts.map(...)` in your render function so you actually tap into the current props, not whatever you cached way back in the deep dark past of when the constructor got called.

Comment: Blarg! I always fear that my problem will turn out to be something idiotic like this. I did `this.props.data.map` and it worked. I rebinded it initially simply to keep the name as `posts`, rather than change the template (in the end I didn't need to do any changing anyway). I think this was left-over from a previous iteration, and didn't know/understand that is was locking in the value. Thanks for looking at that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause component will re-render when props or state update. In your state full component `constructor` only invoke once. So this.post not updated. You can fix that in 2 way

Change `this.posts` when props component will change

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
  this.posts = nextProps.posts
}
```

Or use directly `props.post` in render (this better)

```
return this.props.posts.map((post, index) => {...})
```

Comment: While both answers here solved my issue, I am marking this as correct b/c you use offer two solutions, and use `componentWillReceiveProps` which is something I did not think of (thus teaching me something). +1 for that part of the answer (even though I am not going to use it here;)

Comment: Thank you @MoteZart

Answer (score 1):

```
class Posts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return this.props.data.map((post, index) => {
     return (
        <div className="comment" key={index}>
          <div className="by">{post.by}</div>
          <div className="id">{post.id}</div>
        </div>
      )
    })
  }
 }
```

First of all try something like this instead of initializing the posts in constructor. In your case it might me trying to render before initializing this.posts

Comment: U are right. I updated it and it works now [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drumgod/pbsv02jL/77/). Always appreciative of debugging efforts like yours!